# Two similar bottom sheets but one needs childFragmentManager and other one parentFragmentManager! Why?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bottomsheetdialog, android-fragment-manager

I accept that I am not master in fragment manager. But I expect that two similar BottomSheets behave similarly.

I have a `CustomBottomSheet` (extend of `BottomSheetDialogFragment`). I have created a new instance of that in fragment A and another new instance of that inside of the MyUtility class:

```
FragmentA

MyUtility mu = new MyUtility(FragmentA.this);

CustomBottomSheet.NewInstance().show(getChildFragmentManager(), null);
```

And in `MyUtility.java`

```
CustomBottomSheet.NewInstance().show(fragment.getChildFragmentManager(), null);
```

for getting the results of these bottom Sheets first one needs `getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener ...` and second one needs `getChildFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener ...`.

Why do they behave differently?

Comment: If you are adding the Fragment to the same FragmentManager, then the same FragmentManager is going to be getting results.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: what do you mean by "adding the Fragment to the same FragmentManager"? I am using Navigation components and I don't remember if I've added any FragmentManager.

Comment: If you are using the Navigation component, is there a reason you aren't using a `<dialog>` destination for your custom bottom sheets? It supports any kind of `DialogFragment`, including any `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I don't remember but I have an issue with fragments in Navigation component that before navigating to new destination, the destination fragment file name appear in toolbar for a very short time (in low memory phones it is common) then it shows the fragment "label". So I thought that it could be better to not use dialog in Navigation component as possible as.

Comment: Dialog destination labels don't appear in the Toolbar if you are using [Navigation 2.6.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.6.0-alpha02) or higher, since that's when that big was fixed.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: You are right. My previous Navigation component version was `2.3.0-beta01`. Now it is `2.7.0` and it is working fine. Thanks for this big suggestion. But without using Navigation component, my question still valid.